# (C++) Specific values in an array

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm not sure how to title my question, but here goes. I am testing some features, and I have hit a snag.

What I want to know is how can I set up a "for" or "if" statement to only put values in an array that meet a criteria? For example, find every divisor for a number, but only put factors in an array.

Any help would be loved, source code can be provided if needed :). Yes, I am new, so be gentle!

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int n;
    int counter = 1;
    cout << "What number would you like to use? ";
    cin >> n;
    int DiviArray[n];
    for (int k=0,j=1;k<n;k++,j++)
    {
        DiviArray[k] = n-k;
    }
    int k = 3;
    int factn[n];
    cout << "Factors of " << n << ": " << endl;

    for (int i=0, j=1;i<n;i++,j++)
    {
        factn[i] = n/DiviArray[i];
        if(factn[i]*DiviArray[i]==n)
        {
            cout << counter << ". " << factn[i] << " x " << DiviArray[i] << endl;
            counter++;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: Decided to go with vectors, not sure if I can get it to work, but thanks for the feedback guys :)

Comment: Yes your source code or your ideas about how to do it.

Comment: @Als http://pastebin.com/AHjVLyWF I am unsure how to do it. I can get it to print all the values that match, but every other value gets put into the array as well :/

Comment: I've tried adding other parameters to the if statement, but it won't have it :/

Comment: Well in that, it takes in 2 numbers, n and k, and finds k-possibilities for n. At the moment I just want it to store every factor in an array, to no avail :/.

Comment: I'm thinking of having 2 arrays, one that stores everything, and would be deleted after use, and one that has factors passed to it. Would that work or is there something easier?

Comment: Why do you always have a `j` in your `for`s and you never use them?

Comment: @Shahbaz j is a red herring :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't know in advance how many values will meet the condition, you should use a `std::vector`.

As a benefit, it keeps track of how many elements you've already added, so `push_back` will always use the next available index.

This also fixes

```
cin >> n;
int DiviArray[n];
```

which isn't legal C++.

Comment: (Deleted comment: "How would I implement vectors then?") With dynamic allocation, and copying contents whenever the vector must grow.

Comment: `std::vector` is provided by the standard library (hence the name). You do not need to "implement" it. You need to **use** it. It is used very much like an array. The `.push_back()` method appends to the end, after first ensuring that the storage is big enough. It does all of that for you automatically.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to put the values into the array that match the condition, then you should only put a number into the array when the condition is matched. To do that, the statement that puts a number into the array has to be inside the if-block for the condition. I hope I don't need to explain why :)

This is the only time in your program where you actually do want two indices: one that is incremented every time through the loop (to count how many times to run the process), and one that is incremented only when you put a number in the array (to figure out where the next number goes). Everywhere else, you've created a completely useless `j` variable (the uselessness should be apparent from the fact that there is no code that actually uses the value, only code to set it).

Comment: Yes, the j used to be a line number, but counter replaced it and I forgot to remove it. What you're saying makes sense, but it doesn't really answer what I'm asking. I want the factn array to only have the factors, not numbers that don't multiply back.

Comment: It answers the question just fine. Your question is "how do I make sure only the factors go into the array?" The answer is "take the code that puts numbers into the array, and put it **inside** the 'do this part only if the number is a factor' block".